# UIWebView - Autofill Email/Username field not working

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, autofill

There're many posts on autofilling email/username and password fields in `UIWebView`, I tried all the ways possible but couldn't fill email/username field. However, filling password is working perfectly.

Below is the code I've been dealing with so far.

```
// not working    
NSString *loadUsernameJS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var inputFields = document.querySelectorAll(\"input[type='text']\"); \
  for (var i = inputFields.length >>> 0; i--;) { 
    inputFields[i].value = '%@';
  }", savedUsername];

// working!    
NSString *loadPasswordJS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var passFields = document.querySelectorAll(\"input[type='password']\"); \
  for (var i = passFields.length>>> 0; i--;) { 
    passFields[i].value ='%@';
  }", savedPassword];

[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: loadUsernameJS];
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: loadPasswordJS];
```

I don't want to use `document.getElementById()` method as some websites accept email or username for login.

I also have tried...

```
NSString *loadUsernameJS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var inputFields = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); \ for (var i = inputFields.length >>> 0; i--;) { if(inputFields[i].name == 'username') inputFields[i].value = '%@';}", savedUsername];
```

But still no success.